# hive convert PHT time to UTC

Tags: time, hive, timezone, hiveql

```
select to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'IST');
```

is converting to `utc` from `ist`.
but,

```
select to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'PHT');
```

`PHT` time is not converting, it simply returning current timestamp in `utc`.

```
select current_timestamp(),to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'PHT');

| 2019-07-10 07:52:29.795  | 2019-07-10 07:52:29.795  |
```

returning `utc` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'PHT'` timezine is not recognized because [java.time.ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS) does not contain such zone, it contains `IST` though. Use GMT offset notation like this:

```
hive> select current_timestamp(),to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'GMT+8:00');
OK
2019-07-10 23:21:24.743 2019-07-10 15:21:24.743
Time taken: 0.096 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I am not completely sure is it `GMT+8:00` in Phillipines or should it be `GMT-8:00`, you should know better, `to_utc_timestamp()` will work correctly if you specify correct GMT offset. And there is no daylight saving time in Manilla hence this method should work fine.

Asia/Manila also works fine and as @F.Lazarescu mentioned this is better to use timezone identifier instead of GMT offset because daylight saving will be counted if applicable:

```
select current_timestamp(),to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'Asia/Manila');
OK
2019-07-11 23:09:47.257 2019-07-11 15:09:47.257
Time taken: 4.029 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Have a look at this rather useful article also: [Watch out for timezones with Sqoop, Hive, Impala and Spark](https://boristyukin.com/watch-out-for-timezones-with-sqoop-hive-impala-and-spark-2/)

Comment: if you look into the link you posted (Watch out for timezones ..) you will see that in one of the examples, he used in the same way the utc parameter from to_utc_timestamp function as I did in my example: extract from website:`from_utc_timestamp(begin_effective_dt_tm,'America/New_York') AS local_time`

Comment: Also I found this on the same website: **Always use time zone identifiers for the region like America/New_York or America/Denver, not like EST or CST. This is a common mistake as the latter would not account for daylight savings time! There is a nice list here. Proper time zone identifiers are composed of the name of a continent or ocean and a name of a representative location within this area (typically the name of the largest city).**

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the continent/capital of country:

```
select to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'Asia/Manila');
```

Comment: @leftjoin, strange .. in Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.14.2 works well (tested before commented). It shows our time - 8h. I gived this solution because in our Datalake Production environment, we use this kind of transformation and it works fine. Good to know that in a upper version isn't supported anymore; maybe we need to change it. Thanks!

Comment: `select current_timestamp(),to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'Asia/Manilla');
OK
2019-07-11 22:57:54.011 2019-07-11 22:57:54.011`

Comment: Finally checked one more time and found it was a bug. It is Manila, not Manilla. It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use time zone abbreviations as identifiers.  `IST` could be `India Standard Time`, `Israel Standard Time` or `Ireland Standard Time`.  (There are lots of other ambiguities.)

- If by `IST` you meant India, then use `'Asia/Kolkata'`
- If by `IST` you meant Israel, then use `'Asia/Jerusalem'`
- If by `IST` you meant Irelant, then use `'Europe/Dublin'`
- Instead of `PHT`, use `'Asia/Manila'` for the Philippines

See the [list of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on Wikipedia for the complete list.